# Migrating application servers to new domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, best-practices, entra-domain-services

I work in a corporate environment which has recently been merged with another like business. There is an ongoing project to take our legacy Windows Servers and migrate them to an entirely new Windows Domain. From a logistics standpoint, I'm thinking we'll have to re-do ALL of our IIS SSL certificates, when the machine is migrated. I'm also assuming all the fully qualified domain names will no longer be route-able.

Would there be any way to migrate these machines to a new domain, but still keep the existing DNS records (and essentially, domain internally) so we wouldn't have to change our SSL certificates? 
A consulting company is doing the migration, and I'd MUCH rather offer them a solution that wouldn't have me renewing about 80 SSL certs.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your old domain is going away, then I think one option would be to create a new DNS zone on the new Active Directory domain controllers with the name of your old domain. Then add the A records to the new zone. After your IIS servers are in the new domain, point their DNS to the new AD DNS servers and lookups to the old domain should resolve properly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by changing domain you will keep the old IP addresses of servers. When you migrate servers to new domain you can keep the legacy domain zone in DNS server. By doing this you have two FQDN for one ip address. If you want to use new domain as well; you should add all records to new domain in dns and add certificate in servers. You should also add host header for web applications in IIS servers.